# Attribute a code for every color

Tags: vb.net, graphics, drawing

Is there any way to attribute a code for every color, and be able to read them? Programatically I mean.
My target is to convert an image into code, then convert it back to image.

Comment: So, like, a BMP file?

Comment: Well, somehow...
The id's of the colors must not be the same as the default, and the code will be a txt file, then the text will be converted into an image throught the program

Comment: I guess it depends on what you're doing currently. Could you show us some code possibly? I don't know if you want to apply this to an image file or some pixel array in memory of some sort :o

Comment: It's applied to an image. Each pixel of the image is converted into his color code, then exported as txt file. The text file is converted back to the image then.

Comment: Well, what part of that are you having trouble with? (Also, what image format are you loading?)

Comment: It's hard to figure out how to attribute a custom id for EVERY color then to use those id's to convert image to text and vice versa. The image format would be png or bmp. Most likely png

Comment: Why don't you use the RGB value of the pixel as the code?

Comment: my target is to make the text file as small (is size) as I can, but maybe the RGB codes would work better. But I still can't figure out how to convert every pixel to rgb code

Comment: Why do you need to save an image to a text file in this manner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each color has 4 fields (For some images, you only have 3 fields with meaningful information)

These fields include:

- Alpha (`A`) (This represents opacity of the pixel)
- Red (`R`) (Red intensity)
- Green (`G`) (Green intensity)
- Blue (`B`) (Blue intensity)

What you would do is read them and generate a code string for each one by concatenating the values to one another.

This can most likely be considered pseudo-code as I did not check if it compiles, but you should be doing something along the lines of this.

```
Dim pixelColor As Color
Dim image As BitMap = New BitMap("your_image.png")

Dim a As String
Dim r As String
Dim b As String
Dim g As String

Dim fileString As New StringBuilder()

fileString.AppendLine(image.Size.Width.ToString())
fileString.AppendLine(image.Size.Height.ToString())

' Loop over all pixels
For y As Integer = 0 To image.Size.Height - 1
    For x As Integer = 0 To image.Size.Width - 1
        pixelColor = image.GetPixel(x, y)

        ' get ARGB values as strings
        a = pixelColor.A.ToString()
        r = pixelColor.R.ToString()
        g = pixelColor.G.ToString()
        b = pixelColor.B.ToString()

        ' Append the colors, one pixel per line
        fileString.AppendLine(a & " " & r & " " & g & " " & b)
    Next
Next

Using file As New StreamWriter("image_data.txt")
    outfile.Write(fileString.ToString())
End Using
```

Again, this probably doesn't compile. (I don't have a compiler with me at the moment)

**edit:**
I realized that the width and height need to be stored as well.

---

As for reading the file:

```
Dim file As System.IO.StreamReader
file = File.OpenText("text_file.txt")

Dim width As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(file.ReadLine)
Dim height As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(file.ReadLine)

Dim image As BitMap = New BitMap(width, height)

Dim currentX As Integer = 0
Dim currentY As Integer = 0

Do Until file.EndOfStream
    Dim line As String = file.ReadLine

    Dim valueArray(4) As String = line.Split(" ")

    Dim a As Integer = Convert.ToInt16(valueArray(0))
    Dim r As Integer = Convert.ToInt16(valueArray(1))
    Dim g As Integer = Convert.ToInt16(valueArray(2))
    Dim b As Integer = Convert.ToInt16(valueArray(3))

    image.SetPixel(currentX, currentY, Color.FromArgb(a, r, g, b))

    currentX = currentX + 1

    If currentX == width Then
        currentX = 0
        currentY = currentY + 1

        If currentY == height Then
            Exit Do ' We're done here.
        End If
    End If
Loop

' At this point, you'll have a BitMap with all the pixels set.
```

Again, consider this pseudo-code.

Comment: With some modifications i've got a list with every pixel as ARGB in one line. How could I build em' up to an image?

Comment: Oh yeah, this is the format of each line: A (space) R (space) G (space) B

Comment: I updated it with a fix to the first one to store image width/height as well.

Comment: Convert.ToInt8 doesn't work. There's only ToInt16 and above...And it says that Color.A is read only, and same for R and G and B

Comment: I'll fix that. :v
Better now?

Answer (score 0):

each color is actually a ARGB color code just get integer value

```
Dim myColor As Color = Color.Red
Dim Code As Integer = myColor.ToArgb()

Dim myColorBack As Color = Color.FromArgb(Code)
```